# set_colorkey does not take out the background color (python)

Tags: python, pygame

I recently asked a question about blitting and using the `set_colorkey` feature in python. I was given the answer to change

```
hg = pygame.image.load('hgfinalredbg.jpg').set_colorkey(red)
```

to

```
hg = pygame.image.load('hgfinalredbg.jpg')
hg.set_colorkey(red)
```

However, when I run my program, the red background of `hgfinalredbg.jpg` does not go away. Am I doing something wrong? I have made sure that my program's definition of red and the background of the picture are both (255,0,0). Also, let me know if you need more lines of code to help.
Here is some more code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
white = (255,255,255)
WINDOWHEIGHT = 720
WINDOWWIDTH = 1280
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 0, 32)
windowSurface.fill(white)
pygame.display.update()
red = (255,0,0)
hgbox = pygame.Rect(0 ,13 ,36 ,72)
hg = pygame.image.load('hgfinalredbg.jpg')
hg.set_colorkey(red)
windowSurface.blit(hg, hgbox)
pygame.display.update()
```

[image: Here is the picture.]

Here is `hgfinalredbg.jpg`.

Comment: Please show us a more [complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and maybe the image would help as well. Try to call the [`convert`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) method of the loaded image/surface: `hg = pygame.image.load('hgfinalredbg.jpg').convert()`.

Comment: I have already tried the `convert` method. I will update my question to give you more code.

Comment: Please post the image as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the red in the image mostly has the value `(254, 0, 0)` not `(255, 0, 0)`, so better clean up the image and save it as .png, because png is a lossless format and the problem could come from the compression of the .jpg file.

Comment: Really? I made it in photoshop and I selected `(255,0,0)` for my red. Is there any part of my image that has `(255,0,0)` as the background color?

Comment: The compression of the jpg file probably caused the problem.

Comment: How do you think I could avoid this?

Comment: Clean the image in Photoshop and save it as a .png file. I've already tried to do that and it works fine.

Comment: By clean do you mean take out the background?

Comment: You can either make the background transparent in Photoshop and then call `.convert_alpha()` in pygame or just make sure that every red pixel has the value (255, 0, 0) and keep using `set_colorkey(red)` in pygame.

Comment: It worked! I probably should have tried that sooner. Thanks for your help!